# Google Maps Multiple markers in array

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Map locations array like this

```
var locations = [
      ['bobcat', '100.212','-100.232',  4],
      ['car', '200.212','-200.232',  4],...and so on...
            ];
```

I have the latitude and longitudes inside a php array....and there are a lot of them. They Keep changing as well so i cant really hard code them every time a new one is added. I can echo the php array value in place of the lat and longs and it works too. I basically want a loop so it automatically writes the whole line of array indexes inside location

like this

```
 var locations = [
     for(i=0;i<array.size;i++)
        {
          [phpItemType[i], phpLatVar[i],phpLongVar[i],  phpNumber[i]],
        }
             ];
```

How can I do this? 
I hope the question is clear. 
Please let me know. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the code in JavaScript, may be this will help

```
var locations =[];
for(i=0;i<array.size;i++)
{
    var tempArray = [];
    tempArray.push(phpItemType[i], phpLatVar[i],phpLongVar[i],  phpNumber[i]);
    locations.push(tempArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you notice though, the brackets arent data types. They are array brackets.Here: ['bobcat', '100.212','-100.232',  4],....and neither are the commas. so i dont know a way to insert such things into a array which is where the whole problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: try implementing this, this will result the same bro

Comment: I hope my answer was right, please tick mark it correct to solve the problem